# Equinox OSGi bash script execution and bundle permission

Tags: bash, osgi, bundle, containers, equinox

I searched around and haven't found any appropriate answer to my two questions:

Is it possbile to execute bash script from inside the (Exuinox) OSGi bundle?

Is it possible to add specific permission just to one bundle inside (Equinox) OSGi container?

Description by example: We are running the (Equinox) OSGi as a special user (`userA`) and this user have some special permission on the OS. And now we want to grant these special permissions only to specific bundle, and all the other bundles shouldn't have this permissions.

Thank you!

Best!

Answer (score 0):

OSGi bundles hold Java code. So anything Java can do, you can do. So you can Runtime.exec bash.